# How can I query denormalized table and get associated data in result-set?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have a table which contains some denormalized data something like the following (fake to simplify my question):

**Book Table**

`ID, Title, Author-Name, Publisher-Name, Category`

In another table I have something like the following:

**Author Table**

`ID, Author-Name, Address`

**Publisher Table**

`ID, Publisher-Name, Address`

Assume that `Publisher-Name` and `Author-Name` are always unique.

**Desired Result-Set**

Now, all I want to do is create a query that creates a result-set that includes :

```
 1. all columns from Book table
 2. Author.ID 
 3. Publisher.ID
```

The final result set would look something like the following:

**Result-set Columns**

`ID, Title, Author-Name, Author.ID as [AuthorID], Publisher-Name, Publisher.ID as [PublisherID] Category`

Let's say there are two rows in the Book Table, then the result-set would have two rows which include the appropriate values for the Author.ID and Publisher.ID, because the lookup has been done in the query and returned in the result-set.

**What I've Tried : join**

I've tried using various joins but I always get `more rows than just two rows`, because the join seems to join on the `Publisher.ID` AND the `Author.ID` and I `get 1 row` for each of them which ends up giving me `4` rows instead of `2`.

**Sample Data**

**Books**

```
1, 'All The Time', 'Fred Smith', 'Big Pub Co.', 'non-fiction'
2, 'Biggest Title Ever', 'John Jones', 'Small Pub Co.', 'fiction'
```

**Authors**

```
100, 'Fred Smith', 'Yukon, AK'
101, 'John Jones', 'Happy, VT'
```

**Publishers**

```
300, 'Big Pub Co', 'Angry, IL'
301, 'Small Pub Co', 'Someplace, IN'
```

**Expected Result-Set**

```
1, 'All The Time', 'Fred Smith', 100, 'Big Pub Co.', 300, 'non-fiction'
2, 'Biggest Title Ever', 'John Jones', 101, 'Small Pub Co.' 301, 'fiction'
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? that really help

Comment: Share your query where you've used `join`.

Comment: @D-Shih Added sample data.

Comment: missing dots in Publisher ?

Comment: If it doesn't already exist, you should build out an associative table between books and authors, in case 2 authors with the same name exist, same deal with publishers.

Comment: Constraints are not needed to query. Normalization level doesn't matter. What is necessary & sufficient is what the tables mean. You do not clearly describe what rows you want in the result. Eg talk about "lookup" is vague. Say what rows go in your base tables in terms of a business situation. Then say what rows go in your query result in terms of a business situation and/or base tables. PS Please format your tables with headings. See [mcve]. [Is there any rule of thumb to construct SQL query from a human-readable description?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097)

Comment: @philipxy wait did you see the expected results section? I described all the data.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Here the simplest guesses from column names happen to also be the meanings of the base & query tables because your query is so simple. But you really don't describe your result clearly in text--your text is not clear & adds nothing to the guessing from column names. My comment mentioned both those aspects--meanings & examples-- in saying how to compose/communicate a query specification generally. That is going to matter when your query is not almost trivial. If you find yourself writing "something like" it means you know you haven't been clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try JOIN` and get your want columns from those tables.

```
SELECT 
    b.ID, 
    b.Title,
    b.[Author-Name],
    a.id,
    p.[Publisher-Name],
    p.id,b.Category
FROM Book b 
JOIN Author a on b.[Author-Name] = a.[Author-Name]
JOIN  Publisher p ON b.[Publisher-Name] = p.[Publisher-Name]
```

Comment: while this is good for the data structure given, it's unfortunately not bulletproof, especially if there's multiple authors or publishers with the same name!

Comment: @user2366842 Very good point.  It looks as if I had two problems and one of those was that there was duplicate data in the publisher and author tables which caused multiple rows to be returned in the original query.

Comment: @raddevus Could you provide more sample data and expect result let me figure out the problem :)

Comment: @D-Shih Thanks for your help.  Feeling a bit bad here because I see that it looks as if the original join query is possibly working but I have duplicate data in sub-tables (join tables) that is causing the duplicate rows in the result-set.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? because It is work in sqlfiddle from your samlpe data https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c29c25b165335076eef771168060b439

Answer (score 2):

So, a few things:

1. Your data is not denormalized, it is (correctly) normalized.
2. You have made an odd decision to store author *name* and publisher *name* in the books table.  This will cause problems if you have two authors or publishers with the same name in their respective tables.  If that is guaranteed never to happen (that is, you require a variant of the name in the case of same-name authors or publishers) then you can get rid of the ID column in their respective tables.
3. The solution to your problem is to use a JOIN as you deduced, but we can't tell where you made your mistake because you *did not show what you tried*.

All that said, it sounds like you accidentally performed a cartesian JOIN, which is where you join multiple tables but fail to provide the *join condition*.

So, I suspect you wrote something along the lines of (there are different ways to express this):

```
FROM Books JOIN Authors JOIN Publishers
```

and you should have written:

```
FROM Books INNER JOIN Authors ON Books.Author-Name = Authors.Author-Name
   INNER JOIN Publishers ON Books.Publisher-Name = Authors.Publisher-Name
```

Comment: Very good "extra" information.  And you are correct, I did the first join (without the inner) and I will try the second one (with the inner) and let you know.

Comment: "Normalized" has two broad meanings--normalized to some "1NF" (which itself has no fixed meaning) & normalization to higher NFs. Apparently you don't mean the latter in your first bullet because that would contradict your second bullet. But presumably it's what @raddevus meant when they used it.

Comment: @philipxy My use of denormalized was in reference to the string values that are copied into the Book table for author and publisher name instead of depending on the author.Id publisher.id and forcing another lookup. It was a loose interpretation of denormalization mostly in an attempt to point out the oddity of author name/ publisher name. The reason for that data in real solution is so the service can do one query to the Book table and have info it needs without the extra query or join. Thanks

Comment: @raddevus Thanks. It is more helpful to always put in the effort to say what you mean, instead of writing something that doesn't say what you mean. (See my last comment on the question.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Inner i would suggest you left join in case there won't be match between tables.

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM
    BookTable BOOK
    LEFT JOIN
    AuthorTable AT
        ON AT.Author-Name = BOOK.Author-Name
    LEFT JOIN
    PublisherTable PT
        ON PT.Publisher-Name = BOOK.Publisher-Name
```

However for take sure your rows from Book Table wont be multiplied: use outer apply:

```
SELECT
    BOOK.ID,
    BOOK.Title,
    BOOK.Author-Name,
    AT.ID AS AuthorID,
    BOOK.Publisher-Name,
    PT.ID AS PublisherID,
    BOOK.Category
FROM
    BookTable BOOK
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM AuthorTable AT WHERE AT.Author-Name = BOOK.Author-Name) AT
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM PublisherTable PT WHERE PT.Publisher-Name = BOOK.Publisher-Name) PT
```